# Keras tensorflow training from scratch with imagenet weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use `inception_resnet_v2` to train my own human pose estimation model. This is a regression problem and I need a fully connected layer on top without activation function, thus standard APIs are not good for my case.

The code below works fine, but I fear that that `session.run(init)` will reset the weights to random instead of using `imagenet`.

Is there a way out? If I remove session init, it throws an error.

```
def inception_resnet_v2():

    model = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False,
                      weights='imagenet',
                      input_shape=(FLAGS.resize_input_image,
                                   FLAGS.resize_input_image, 3))
    x = model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(28, activation=None, name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(input=model.input, output=x)

    print(model.summary())

    return model 

model = inception_resnet_v2()
network = model(images)

_, mean_loss = regression_loss.loss_func(joints_gt, is_valid_joint, network)
train_op = optimizer.rms_prop(mean_loss=mean_loss,   global_step=global_step)

init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
            tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:

    # Initialize variables
    sess.run(init)
```

Comment: You can do this directly in Keras, why are you combining it with TensorFlow?

Comment: As i said I am using my own optimizer, loss function and have data in tf format..

Comment: It is very strange!! The problem is not with vgg 16 models but with inception v3 and inception resnet models when I start the session before hand with K.set_session(sess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply to save the model and re load it after initializing variables.

```
    def inception_resnet_v2():

model = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False,
                  weights='imagenet',
                  input_shape=(FLAGS.resize_input_image,
                               FLAGS.resize_input_image, 3))
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(28, activation=None, name='predictions')(x)
model = Model(input=model.input, output=x)

print(model.summary())

return model 

model = inception_resnet_v2()
**model.save('mymodel.h5')**
network = model(images)

_, mean_loss = regression_loss.loss_func(joints_gt, is_valid_joint, network)
train_op = optimizer.rms_prop(mean_loss=mean_loss,      global_step=global_step)

init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
            tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:

    # Initialize variables
    sess.run(init)
    **model.load('mymodel.h5')**
```